# A ship goes into a void and discovers a missing space station and also a legendary ship from the past. Working together they recreate the legend

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find out the name of a book. The main ship has someone who secretly worked on the space station before it disappeared into this void. The second ship is a really important historical vessel, famous for creating peace where it had seemed impossible.

The space station was already shuttered when it disappeared, if I remember correctly. The rift or whatever it is seems to exist outside time in some way. The big ship and the legendary one both arrived recently, and go back to a time that is the future for the legendary folks, and real-time for the big ship.

The time loop aspect is really unoriginal except that you wonder how they'll pull it off. And then they do.

Comment: This feels a bit like *Babylon 5*...

Comment: Can you remember: how old you were when you read this (or the reading age it was aimed at), which country you were in, and what year this was? Was there a cover picture you can describe?

Comment: This has vague whiffs of C. J. Cherreh's *Port Eternity*.

Comment: This was in the US, recently (like the last 10 years), and it was for adults. I read it on Kindle so I don't know the cover. I'll go through my kindle books and see if I can find some candidates.

Comment: Could it have been The Last Watch by J.S. Dawes? I can't find enough of a summary to tell. Or a Big Ship at the Edge of the Universe by Alex White?

Comment: Are the space station and the second (legendary) ship still crewed?  How long have they been lost?  (Did they disappear at the same time?  Was there a search for them when they disappeared?)  Has time elapsed at the same rate in the void as in the original universe?

Comment: The space station was already shuttered when it disappeared, if I remember correctly. The rift or whatever it is seems to exist outside time in some way. The big ship and the legendary one both arrived recently, and go back to a time that is the future for the legendary folks, and real-time for the big ship.

Comment: I think you left something out of your description. All of a sodden you tell us "The time loop aspect is really unoriginal . .." but you haven't said anything about a time loop up to that point (or afterwards). Is there a "time loop" in the story? Maybe you could improve your question by telling us something about the "time loop".

Answer (score 3):

I just pulled together a few threads in my brain, and I'm wondering if you read one of the [*Diving Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?28856) novels by (2009-ongoing) by Kristine Kathryn Rusch, especially with the additional details you added in your comment.

In the second book, [*City of Ruins*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1239151), Boss and her crew discover/retrieve a ship of the legendary Fleet, the *Ivoire*, that has been trapped somewhere outside of normal spacetime for 5000 years.  (It has only been 15 days experienced for the crew of the *Ivoire*.)

The Fleet are something like a peripatetic, embryonic version of Banks' *Culture*, in that they are a space-going society part of whose raison d'être was to try to help other societies, broker peace, etc.  It was on a peacekeeping mission that *Ivoire* was attacked and ended up in the negative space wedgie that trapped it for 5000 years.

The space station you mention might be the ancient (contemporaneous with the *Ivoire*) Starbase Kappa, which is now known as "The Room of Lost Souls."  Only part of the Starbase is currently visible, most of it being trapped in another spacetime glitch, another manifestation of which is the Room itself.  (The partial structure remaining visible is named for the Room it contains.)  The Room of Lost Souls is a source/location of strange effects and illusions; most people who enter end up aging hundreds of thousands of times faster than normal and die before they can leave, but the luckier ones just tend to go insane.

Boss doesn't tell anyone this, but she has been in the Room of Lost Souls itself, twice, and has survived.

The captain of the *Ivoire*, Coop, would prefer to track down the Fleet and rejoin it, but, failing that, is willing to attempt to resurrect the Fleet with their own ships to resume its mission.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn’t really a space station involved, this has some similarities with [*A Talent For War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Talent_for_War) by Jack McDevitt, so it’s worth checking out they linked description (presented below as well) to see if it rings any bells. It does concern the rediscovery of a famous spaceship which was instrumental in winning an impossible war.

> “…the story of a search by Alex Benedict, the protagonist, to discover the nature of a mysterious project Alex's uncle had been working on when the interstellar passenger ship, on which his uncle was a passenger, was lost in space. This investigation leads deep into the history of a war between human civilization and a neighboring alien civilization and challenges the foundation mythos of the current human government.”

Comment: Similar in that way, but no.